# Cloning react components to new windows via web worker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-worker

I'm looking for a way to move a react component with it's state across windows/tabs to provide an interactive split screen display to our interface.

Currently I have a shared web worker setup where the 2 windows are communicating to each other and passing data between when a component is to be be moved.

What I'm struggling with is passing the react component across and having the new window render it out. I've been thinking about a few possibilities, the first using `renderToString()` on that component and passing this across via the web worker to the new window however I'm not sure on the correct implementation for loading that component back in as it's done on the client directly. Have also looked at using a redux store and keeping this context in the web worker so the state is remapped.

Ideally I'm wanting a kind of data representation of the component in it's current state which I can encode/decode.

Any idea is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did my answer help ?

Answer (score 0):

You may **see React components as a representation of a state**.

So what you have to share between your windows/tabs is a state.
The react components will synchronize if your react application handle the state changes.

If you have a backend in your stack, you may synchronize the state with the backend in all windows/tabs.

If you want "realtime" clientside synchronisation, you may go with your shared web worker solution, and just share a **serializable state**.

If you use redux, you could maybe use [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) with a custom "web worker" storage implementation.